# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape' , how sould i fix this type of error?

Tags: python-3.x

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

I am trying to make the code for row and column for given array.
and the top line is my error, how can it be fixed?

```
def comuteFinalGrades(grades):
    a=[]
    N, M = grades.shape
```

Comment: `grades` is a list and a list doesn't have a `shape` attribute. Where (and how) do you call this function, and what did you expect `grades` to be?

Comment: `grades` seems to be a python `list` (and should probably be a `numpy.array`). your question is unclear.

Comment: Actually, the code is a bit long so, I just uploaded that much, I call the finalGrade at the end, but this doesn't take this as a shape, as it seems from the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the list into numpy array and then You can use the shape attribute.

```
import numpy as np
def comuteFinalGrades(grades):
    grades=np.array(grades)
    a=[]
    N, M = grades.shape
```

Comment: No this is creating problem, may be I can share my whole code.

Comment: import numpy as np
from roundgrade import roundGrades

def comuteFinalGrades(grades):
    a=[]
    N, M = grades.shape
    if M==1:
        gradesFinal = roundGrades(grades)
        for i in range(N):
            if grades[i]==-3:
                gradesFinal = -3
            if grades[i]!=-3:
                g=min(grades)
                a.append(g)
                G=np.delete(grades,g)
                F=np.mean(G)
                gradesFinal = roundGrades(F)
    return gradesFinal
print(comuteFinalGrades([[1,2,3],[0,9,8],[0,5,6]]))

Comment: ops , it looks so conjusted, I'm a new user of this website, sorry for the mess.

Comment: @Vatsal, I have updated the code and call the numpy conversion inside the method. Try it now.

Comment: Yup, got it .... It was taking this as list not array

Comment: Thanks, I got the output at least, but that's showing me something wrong though.

Comment: Oh yeah , that's not wrong just half answer, But thanks though...